# Proof that from $\emptyset \vDash B$ follows that B must be a tautology

Tags: logic

Preliminaries: A, B = variables for wff‘s in some formal language, I = interpretation/model or truth-value-assignment of some wff.

We start with a definition: $\Sigma \vDash B \leftrightarrow \forall I:(\forall A \in \Sigma \to A(I) = 1) \to B(I) = 1$.

Let $\Sigma = \emptyset$, so we get $\emptyset \vDash B \leftrightarrow \forall I:(\forall A \in \emptyset \to A(I) = 1) \to B(I) = 1$ which we can farther shorten to $\emptyset \vDash B \leftrightarrow \forall I:\top \to B(I) = 1$.

Now assume $\emptyset \vDash B$. Then follows $\forall I:\top \to B(I) = 1$. But this implication is only true if B cannot be false in any case (= tautology). $\square$

Is this correct?

Comment: Would you clean up your definition of $\Sigma \models B$? I believe what you're looking for is something like $\Sigma \models B$ if and only if for all variable assignments $M$, if for all $A \in \Sigma$, $m(A) = 1$, then $m(B) = 1$.

Comment: Ok, I did clean up the definition and the follow-up‘s. I just used 
I
 = interpretation/model (which is simple truth-value-assignment in propositional logic) because it has a wider meaning and now the proof applies for any classical logic. True? Do you think it‘s ok now?

Comment: Yes, the proof is fine now. Depending on the precise definition of a tautology, you may be able to slightly shorten it. If the definition is $\forall I, B(I) = 1$, then you don't need to talk about $B$ not being false in any case.